# Function to test variable in Postgres insert

Tags: postgresql

1. I have a trigger rule on a table insert
2. I wish to insert value in another table following that insert
3. The insert only happen in a specific condition

Current code (that work)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."raw_data_insert"()
  RETURNS "pg_catalog"."trigger" AS $BODY$
    DECLARE v_TitleId JSON;
    DECLARE v_EventName JSON;
    DECLARE v_EntityId JSON;
    DECLARE v_ItemId JSON;
    
   BEGIN
     v_TitleId = new.data::json->'TitleId';
     v_EventName = new.data::json->'EventName';
     v_EntityId = new.data::json->'EntityId';
     v_ItemId = new.data::json->'ItemId';
     
     INSERT INTO player_inventory_item_added(titleid, playerid, itemid, timestamp, expiration) VALUES (v_TitleId, v_EntityId, v_ItemId, new.ts, NULL);
   RETURN NEW;      
        
   END;
 
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
```

What I would love to do:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."raw_data_insert"()
  RETURNS "pg_catalog"."trigger" AS $BODY$
    DECLARE v_TitleId JSON;
    DECLARE v_EventName JSON;
    DECLARE v_EntityId JSON;
    DECLARE v_ItemId JSON;
    
   BEGIN
     v_TitleId = new.data::json->'TitleId';
     v_EventName = new.data::json->'EventName';
     v_EntityId = new.data::json->'EntityId';
     v_ItemId = new.data::json->'ItemId';
     
     IF v_EventName = "player_inventory_item_added" then
     
     INSERT INTO player_inventory_item_added(titleid, playerid, itemid, timestamp, expiration) VALUES (v_TitleId, v_EntityId, v_ItemId, new.ts, NULL);
   RETURN NEW;
            
    end if;     
        
   END;
 
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
```

My condition trigger a server error. The code without condition work fine.

I also noticed that all my json value return the value + "". For example, when I insert v_EventName in my table, I get **"player_inventory_item_added"** instead of **player_inventory_item_added**.

Sorry for the 'noob' question, I did try every combination I could find in the documentation. IS, ==, etc.. I even tested basic int value condition,  nothing work.

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: It's `'"player_inventory_item_added"'` - a postgres literal (apostrophes) of a json value, specifically a json string literal (quotes).

Comment: Thanks! But the If condition still throw an error with or without literal apostrophes. :(

Comment: Btw you might want to put the `RETURN NEW` outside of the `IF` block

Comment: What data type are those columns in `player_inventory_item_added`? It seems strange to me, that you are storing scalar values in JSON columns. And why isn't the column `data` defined as `jsonb` (or at least `json`) if you are clearly storing JSON data in it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `'"player_inventory_item_added"'` - a [postgres constant literal](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS) (apostrophes) of a json value, specifically a json string literal (quotes). Quotes alone make it an escaped [postgres identifier](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) (name of an entity such as variable / column / table etc), but nothing with the name `player_inventory_item_added` exists in the scope of that function.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! :) But it still throw an Internal "Server Error" as soon as I add this condition. In this case I added IF v_EventName = '"player_inventory_item_added"' then but it automatically crashed.

Comment: Maybe make it more explicit, using `'"player_inventory_item_added"'::json`. But it shouldn't throw an "Internal server error", it should at least provide a useful error message in the postgres logs